# Sci-Fi story where human astronauts barf up their guts like sea cucumbers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

I read a short story where astronauts became infected with something that made them barf up their insides and regrow them, like sea cucumbers. In the end, this is how one of the characters learns that his wife cheated on him; she slept with someone who had been infected, became infected herself, and yakked her guts up when her husband surprised her. I think this was on the old Sci Fi Channel website, but google and archive.org were no help. I googled "sci-fi story sea cucumber," but didn't get what I was looking for.

Pretty sure it's not Mindbridge, either.

Comment: So did it actually say "sea-cucumber" in the story?

Comment: It did. The characters made explicit comparisons to that creature. You'd think that would make it easier to google, but not for me, apparently.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is [The Girl had Guts](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56318) by Theodore Sturgeon.

[image: THE GIRL HAD GUTS by THEODORE STURGEON | When the alien appeared death came too... and horror... and fear that was more terrible than the alien itself...]

> And at last we could discard the fifty or sixty theories that had been
> formed and decide on one: That the primates of Mullygantz II had the
> ability, like a terran sea cucumber, of ejecting their internal organs
> when frightened, and of growing a new set,....
>
> The only problem that remained was to find out exactly how terrans had
> become infected...

Read it at the Internet Archive [here](https://ia800206.us.archive.org/13/items/Venture_v01n01_1957-01_Gorgon776/Venture_v01n01_1957-01_Gorgon776.pdf), in the Venture SF January 1957 issue.

Comment: I remember reading this in the anthology ["Histoires de: Créatures"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?421767). I thought it was a good story, but I didn't understand the title: _"Une fille qui en a"_ - which is the colloquial counterpart of _"A girl who has guts"_, but there are no "guts" left in the french wording, it is left unspecified what she would have - it would be "courage", "balls"  and, further down the list, "entrails": [avoir des tripes](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/avoir%20des%20tripes). Now I understand...

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for the answer, it's been bothering me literally for years.

Comment: @Jessica you are welcome, and welcome to scifi stack exchange! Since you've indicated that this is the answer, please mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark beside it.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing that out and welcoming a newbie.